# OSX Matlab charset encoding

Tags: macos, matlab, character-encoding

I bought a new mac computer and I installed matlab 2014a on it. The problem I'm quite experiencing is weird and I couldn't find a way to fix this so far. I searched for the whole day yesterday and part of this morning, with no lucky.

I have a folder called Università and matlab has problem with the accent on it.

```
>> disp('Università');
Universit�
>> feature('DefaultCharacterSet')

ans =

UTF-8
```

I put feature('DefaultCharacterSet','UTF8') on my startup.m, but the only thing changed in the result there.

I read many people had this problem, but I'm not as lucky as them.

Any suggestion will be appreciated.

Cheers

Comment: I can't reproduce your problem on my mac, with R2014a. However a call to `feature('DefaultCharacterSet')` gives ISO-8859-1.

Answer (score 0):

Just solved a similar problem. You might want to change your OS X default language and restart Matlab. Just go to System Preferences - Language & Region - Advanced, and then change the Format Language to your language where these characters are used, and restart Matlab. This got at least umlaut characters working for me. Good luck!

Found from here: http://nl.mathworks.com/help/matlab/matlab_env/setting-locale-on-macintosh-platforms.html